# What is the glide ratio of the Ozone Mojo Power 2?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing

The ozone mojo power 2 is a paramotor wing aimed towards beginners. I am interested in purchasing it, however I have not found any data on the lift to glide ratio. Does anybody know this info?

Comment: I believe EN-A level wings are generally about 7-8.  EN-Bs around 9, EN-Cs/Ds around 10+.  I think you'll find they are all so closely matched performance wise, handling qualities become more important. As a power/glider pilot who wants to protect my legs and back and having watched enough vids of the results of collapses close to the ground,, passive safety would be priority #1. I'd like to get into paragliding, but I have a plantar fasciitis problem with my left foot which prevents me from running.

Comment: Have you tried paramotor trikes? It severely reduces running  and stress on your legs. Hope you get better.

Comment: Thks. The trike config takes away some of the bird like feeling of just being in a harness. Might as well move up to a hang glider trike or an ultralight.